# Citrix mouse clicks off / not working High DPI / Scaling / Multiple Monitors

Tags: scaling, dpi, multiple-monitors, citrix

gonna answer my own question but this has to be more common and I didn't find anyone answering it. I connect to a lot of different clients running many backend versions of citrix and I try to keep my machine on the latest, resorting to VM's when i need a specific version (becoming more rare thankfully)

Anyway this latest issue I could use citrix light just fine but when i launched the ica file it would open and i could use the keyboard but i couldn't seemingly click things in the session and the i discovered upon closer examination that my mouse was offset when trying to click on UI elements in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution per this knowledge base article:
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX230286

Was to set all monitors to the same scaling. I use 3 additional monitors to my surface laptop and the surface laptop defaults to 150% scaling and the others were 100%. I set my laptop to be 100% like the others and voila.

Things are really small on that screen now but i don't use it much and would much rather be able to run the citrix session properly on my other monitors.

Hope this is helpful.